# Employee handbook changes - do I have to be notified or sign?

Tags: employer-relations

They changed the 7 days off. I have been with the company for 15 years.
They changed the employee handbook. I receive no notification. I have not signed updated handbook

Comment: Voting to close becaue the answer to your question is company-policy specific. Redirect your questions to your own HR.

Comment: If you are thinking that they will honor the old days off policy because you didn't sign something, I would suspect that you are wrong.  At least in the US, companies are free to change benefits and you are free to discontinue your employment if you don't like the change. In other countries it may depend on local laws and the specific contract you signed.

Answer (score 2):

I know here in the US, with my current company, they change the employee handbook ( updated policies ) and I haven't been notified or signed anything.  I don't think the **have too**, but they **should**.

When I first joined the company, I signed a document stating that I read it, and part of that initial document included verbiage about the fact they could update the handbook if they feel its necessary.

Note:  *This may be specific to your location ( country, or country/state )*